# React-native one-signal just working at Android and not working at ios

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

So, at the oficial documentation there is this ios implementation, but I can't see logs ate the console.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

Step 5:

import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

```
// OneSignal Initialization
OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);

// promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse will show the native iOS or Android notification permission prompt.
// We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission (See step 8)
OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse();

//Method for handling notifications received while app in foreground
OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(notificationReceivedEvent => {
  console.log("OneSignal: notification will show in foreground:", notificationReceivedEvent);
  let notification = notificationReceivedEvent.getNotification();
  console.log("notification: ", notification);
  const data = notification.additionalData
  console.log("additionalData: ", data);
  // Complete with null means don't show a notification.
  notificationReceivedEvent.complete(notification);
});

//Method for handling notifications opened
OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(notification => {
  console.log("OneSignal: notification opened:", notification);
});
```

I am trying to send push notifications from the oficial one-signal site to my react-native app. Android works fine, but in ios nothing happening.